# Ascending & descending in single query with Aggregate & Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the data like shown below:

```
name  SAL1 SAL2 SAL3
A     10  20   30
B     11  21   31
C     12  22   32
D     13  23   33
```

i was trying to get an additional calculated column, i.e **10 / 25 *100**
[ SAL1 of A / Sum( TOP 2 Sal1 ORDER BY Sal1  DESC ) ]
Instead of considering sum for all the records in the denominator i need to consider only top 2 sal order by sal desc

respectively for the rest of the rows. 
with other columns subsequently.

```
name SAL_calculated
A 40
B 44
C 48
D 52
```

And do order by Asc for name column and Desc for the rest of the columns

Comment: what is the version of SQL Server you are using ?

Comment: It's SQL Server 2012

Comment: Instead of considering sum for all the records in the denominator i need to consider only top 2 sal order by sal desc


i.e 10 / 25 *100 NOT 10 /46 *100 sorry for the changes

i.e  A = 40 not 21.7

Comment: already updated my answer. Please try

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT name, SAL_calculated = SAL * 100.0 / SUM(SAL) OVER ()
FROM   table
ORDER BY name ASC, SAL_calculated DESC
```

for SAL1 of A / Sum(TOP 2 Sal1 ORDER BY Sal1 DESC)

```
select  *, t.SAL1 * 100.0 / c.TOP2_SAL
from    tbl t
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP2_SAL = SUM(SAL1)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT TOP 2 SAL1
            FROM    tbl
            ORDER BY SAL1 desc
        ) c
    ) c
```

Comment: `SELECT name, SAL_calculated = 100.0 * SAL / SUM(SAL) OVER ()` Remember about SQL Server **integer division**! **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/443360)** Otherwise you will get zeros.

Comment: Doesnt the user need sum calculated per column

Comment: get an additional calculated column, i.e 10 / 46 *100..for each column ?

Comment: Squirrel & lad 2025 Thanks for the support.
But wait can you check the requirement again please i have made some changes  

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, SAL1, SAL2, SAL3, 
       ROUND(SAL1 * 1.0 / x.v * 100, 1) AS SAL_calculated
FROM mytable 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(SAL1) FROM mytable) AS x(v)
ORDER BY name, SAL1 DESC, SAL2 DESC, SAL3 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

well here is what i did,

In subquery, We can store aggregation of top n or whole set of records into the variable **a** and then use that variable as denominator.

Declare @a as integer = 0
SELECT @a = 
 (
        SELECT TOP2_SAL = SUM(SAL1)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT TOP 2 SAL1
            FROM    [dbo].[TESTY]
            ORDER BY SAL1 desc
        ) c
    ) 
select 
*, 
t.SAL1 * 100 / @a
from    [dbo].[TESTY] t